# Adding SquashFS support to Ubuntu 10.04 EC2 AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-10.04

I am using Ubuntu provided EC2 AMI for Ubuntu Lucid 10.04 LTS 64-bit and it doesn't come with support for SquashFS built in.

Is there a way to add support, so I can mount a SquashFS filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

`apt-cache search squashfs`

`squashfs-tools` - tool to create and append to squashfs filesystems.

A simple `sudo apt-get install squashfs-tools` should do the trick I think :-)